# Bootstrap Gem doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm importing gem files like this, but the html files in view folder can't show the bootstrap navbar.

```
gem 'devise', '3.4.1'
gem "bootstrap-sass", "~> 3.1.1.0"
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'devise_zxcvbn'
```

This is my application's application.js file.

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

This is my application's application.scss file.

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";

.alert-alert {
  @extend .alert-warning;
}

.alert-notice {
  @extend .alert-info;
}
```

There're no errors in this application but view files can't use the bootstrap themes. For example,`<ul> tag :<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">` there is no navbar on browser. I use Chrome. Please help me to use the bootstrap theme in Rails4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [*bootstrap-sass*](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

> bootstrap-sprockets and bootstrap **should not both be included** in
>   application.js.
>
> bootstrap-sprockets provides individual Bootstrap Javascript files
>   (alert.js or dropdown.js, for example), while bootstrap provides a
>   concatenated file containing all Bootstrap Javascripts.

So keep any one of them and remove the other from `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```